# We think we have a top-seller on/in our hands?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I know this on our hands/in our hands discrepancy has been discussed here in a broad way, but since it's idiomatic, I think it would be helpful to consider a few specific examples, like the one here. Would you use "on our hands" or "in our hands" here, and why?

It refers to something you invented and produced, and you're guessing it will do well on the market. So you're not having anything literally in your hands. You don't know if it's a top-seller yet, you just think it will become one. That's why "on our hands" seems right to me. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *on our hands*.  This is the idiomatic usage that is most common.  It means present before you.

When you say *in our hands* idiomatically it tends to mean that you are responsible for the outcome of it.  As an example:

> The future of the free world is *in our hands.*